# I can't change string encoding on PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
   $str = "Text";
   $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($str));
   echo mb_detect_encoding($str);
?>
```

This code is givin me "ASCII" as output.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string has no UTF-8 specific characters, only ASCII.

Add one in:

```
$str = "Text È";
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($str));
echo mb_detect_encoding($str);
```

You'll get `UTF-8` as output now, as seen in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/SaXgRT).

However, you don't need to run the conversion to get `UTF-8` as output, `mb_detect_encoding()` picks up that the string is `UTF-8` without this step.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, that a purely ASCII "converted" to UTF-8 will be indistinguishable from ASCII.